# How to get Button as Parent on MenuItemFlyoutItem_Click?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I'm building a WinRT Universal app and I have a button and a MenuFlyout attached to it - I'm trying to get the Name and Tag of the button.

XAML:

```
<MenuFlyout x:Key="FlyOutResource">
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="pin to start" Click="PinToStart_Click"/>
</MenuFlyout>

<Button x:Name="ButtonName" Tag="BUTTON TAG" FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource FlyOutResource}" Holding="Button_Holding"/>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Holding(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
}



private void PinToStart_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuFlyoutItem = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
    if (menuFlyoutItem != null)
    {
                        ????
    }
}
```

**How do I get the name of the button (of which the FlyOut is attached to)? DataContext doesn't work.**

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 1):

I am in UWP but am hitting the same issue and do not see a way around it from within the PinToStart_Click Handler.

In your solution, you at least see which button opened the flyout within the Button_Holding handler. I'd recommend storing a reference to the sender in the Button_Holding handler and then access that reference within the PinToStart click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempParent = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child as FrameworkElement);
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: This only returns stuff like StackPanel => Border => Border => MenuItemFlyout but then it ends, doesn't seem to go up to the Button.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I leave a solution

If you name your MenuFlyout:

```
<Button.Flyout>
    <MenuFlyout x:Name="MenuFlyoutContainer">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Tapped="OnMenuFlyoutItem"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
</Button.Flyout>
```

Then on the tapped event you can search for it:

```
private void OnDeletePressed(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var item = (sender as MenuFlyoutItem);
        var itemDataContext = item.DataContext;

        FrameworkElement parent = (item.FindName("MenuFlyoutContainer") as MenuFlyout);
}
```

And voila you have your MenuFlyout instance.

Tested inside DataTemplates on UWP.